# How to use securityMatcher in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I wanted to skip security check for http requests that meet `/app/**` and `/swagger-ui/**` patterns. But after I applied the below spring security configuration, all the http requests return me a HTTP ERROR 403 error, which says the access to localhost is denied.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .securityMatcher(
                        new NegatedRequestMatcher(
                                new OrRequestMatcher(
                                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/app/**"),
                                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui/**")
                                )
                        )
                )
                .cors(withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                        .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/*.*").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAuthority(Constants.AUTHORITY_ADMIN)
                        .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/services/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").hasAuthority(Constants.AUTHORITY_ADMIN)
                        .requestMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/management/health/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(Constants.AUTHORITY_ADMIN)
                )
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to exclude security check for some specific patterns using `securityMatcher` method while ensuring `authorizeHttpRequests` still behaves normal?

Some logs:

```
2023-09-16T20:26:01.936+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/app/test", parameters={}
2023-09-16T20:26:01.938+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-09-16T20:26:01.943+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2023-09-16T20:26:01.944+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2023-09-16T20:26:01.947+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:01.947+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:01.948+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:01.949+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:01.949+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:01.950+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:01.950+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:01.951+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:01.951+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:01.952+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:01.952+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:01.952+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:01.953+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:01.955+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:01.955+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:01.955+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:57.056+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-09-16T20:26:57.056+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-09-16T20:26:57.057+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-09-16T20:26:57.058+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-09-16T20:26:57.059+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/api/authenticate", parameters={}
2023-09-16T20:26:57.059+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-09-16T20:26:57.062+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2023-09-16T20:26:57.062+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2023-09-16T20:26:57.064+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:57.065+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:57.066+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:57.066+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:57.067+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:57.068+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:57.068+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:57.068+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:57.069+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:57.069+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:57.069+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:57.070+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:57.071+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:57.071+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:57.071+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:57.072+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:58.086+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-09-16T20:26:58.087+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-09-16T20:26:58.089+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-09-16T20:26:58.089+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-09-16T20:26:58.090+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/api/authenticate", parameters={}
2023-09-16T20:26:58.101+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-09-16T20:26:58.105+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2023-09-16T20:26:58.105+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2023-09-16T20:26:58.108+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:58.108+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:58.108+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:58.108+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:58.109+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:58.109+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:58.109+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:58.110+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:58.110+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:58.111+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:58.111+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:58.111+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:58.111+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:58.112+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:58.112+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:26:58.112+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.543+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/app/api/authenticate", parameters={}
2023-09-16T20:27:14.545+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-09-16T20:27:14.550+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2023-09-16T20:27:14.552+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2023-09-16T20:27:14.555+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.556+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.556+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.556+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.556+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.556+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.557+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.557+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.558+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.558+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.558+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.558+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.558+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.559+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.559+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.559+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.979+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/app/api/authenticate", parameters={}
2023-09-16T20:27:14.981+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-09-16T20:27:14.986+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2023-09-16T20:27:14.986+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2023-09-16T20:27:14.989+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.989+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.990+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.990+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.990+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.991+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.991+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.992+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.993+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.993+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.994+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.994+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.994+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.994+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.994+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-09-16T20:27:14.995+08:00 DEBUG 8580 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
```

Comment: just telling us that you are getting a 403 isnt helping at all, you need to enable DEBUG logs and show us the actual reason for the 403 as there can be 10 different reasons for a 403. That is very poor debugging on your part.

Comment: @Toerktumlare sorry mate, I've made three API calls and here is the log output

Comment: i dont want logs in comments, use the edit button and include logs etc well formatted

Comment: @Toerktumlare added already

Comment: @Toerktumlare 404 NOT FOUND should be expected cos I haven't added any mappings yet, but all those 3 requests actually returned 403 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is really necessary to skip security filter for specific paths, you can create a [WebSecurityCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityCustomizer.html) Bean and ignore it.

```
 @Bean
 public WebSecurityCustomizer ignoringCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/app/**", "/swagger-ui/**");
 }
```

And also remove this piece of code from `filterChain`config

```
 .securityMatcher(
                        new NegatedRequestMatcher(
                                new OrRequestMatcher(
                                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/app/**"),
                                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui/**")
                                )
                        )
                )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer its a working solution. But I'm wondering is there an approach to keep this `securityMatcher`?

Answer (score 0):

I've refactored the `filterChain` config and applied the below changes now it works:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .securityMatcher(
                        new NegatedRequestMatcher(
                                new OrRequestMatcher(
                                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/app/**"),
                                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui/**"),
                                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/i18n/**"),
                                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/content/**")
                                )
                        )
                )
                .securityMatcher("/**")
//                .securityMatchers()
//                    .requestMatchers(new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/app/**")))
//                    .requestMatchers(new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui/**")))
//                    .requestMatchers("/**")

                .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                        .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/*.*").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAuthority(Constants.AUTHORITY_ADMIN)
                        .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/services/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").hasAuthority(Constants.AUTHORITY_ADMIN)
                        .requestMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/management/health/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(Constants.AUTHORITY_ADMIN)
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        return http.build();
    }
```